# How to fix 'Failed to resolve: com.android.volly:volly:1.1.1'error in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

Unfortunately, I live in Iran and I have to use vpn,I want to know I wanted to know if this is relevant?

> Blockquote

ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.volly:volly:1.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you are using incorrect name while defining dependency. it should be as follows

```
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
```

Comment: Yeah you're right. Thank you. What a ridiculous mistake